How can I make my script to transfer information from a sheet to another, but to an specific column
I'm creating a customer base and in one sheet I created a "window" that will allow me do put the clients info and that info will be transferred to another sheet, but I want to separate the clients depending on the month they came to us. I'm having difficulty with the last row function, because I can't determine the last row of a specific column.
This is what I'm using, but I get an error

Exception: Cannot convert 'triagem 24!B8:E8' to int

My code:
function cadastrar() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var nome = ss.getRange('E10').getValue();
 var proveniencia = ss.getRange('E12').getValue();
 var meio = ss.getRange ('E14').getValue();
 var faturado = ss.getRange('E16').getValue();

 if (nome == '' ||   proveniencia == '' || meio == '' || faturado == '' ) {
     SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Oie, esqueceu de por alguma coisa ai amore!");
     return
 }

 var info = [nome, proveniencia, meio, faturado]

 var ss = ss.getSheetByName('triagem 24');
 ultima_linha = ss.getLastRow();

 for (let i=1; i<5; i++) {
     ss.getRange('triagem 24!B:E', ultima_linha+1).setValue(info[i]);
 }
}

This is where I put the information
And here is where the info is supposed to go
I tried not using the LastRow function, but it unconfigures the entire table.

Use Sheet.appendRow(), like this:
  const info = [null, nome, proveniencia, meio, faturado,];
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('triagem 24');
  sheet.appendRow(info);

To do the same using (an inefficient) loop, use integers as getRange() parameters, like this:
  for (let i = 2; i <= 5; i++) {
    ss.getRange(ultima_linha + 1, i).setValue(info[i]);
  }

See Sheet.appendRow().
To append data starting at the last filled cell of a specific column, try my appendRows_() utility function.

thank you that was helpful, but still didn't solve my problem, I still cannot define in which column and row the info should go

"To append data starting at the last filled cell of a specific column, try my appendRows_() utility function."
